# How can I prevent a new Kobo reader from downloading all my books?

Tags: kobo

I have a lot of books I have purchased from Kobo, and I know that when you get a new reader you have to connect it to a Kobo account (or other social media accounts). I want to connect it to my Kobo account so I can load future purchases easier, but I don't want it to try to download all of my older books as I have already read most of them and they don't need to be on the device.

I know from setting up devices for other people that it will just sort of try to be helpful and download my entire Kobo Library to my device. Is there a way to prevent it from doing it?

Comment: The only way I can think of that you might be able to do this is to delete all of the books from the library on your Kobo Desktop. That should prevent your purchased books from syncing to any of your devices, but I haven't tried it myself. You can always re-download the deleted books from Kobo if you need them later. Of course, you can always let them sync and "delete all" from the reader.